# How to create a border with thickness that gradually decreases along a container in Flutter

Tags: flutter, dart

I have a Container that spans the entire length of the page. While I've successfully added a border on the left, I'm now looking to include borders at both the top and bottom. However, I'm interested in experimenting with a unique design concept; regrettably, I'm uncertain about the steps to accomplish this.

I'd like my border sides to start with a thickness of 4px on the left and gradually taper down along the container's length until they reach 0.5px on the right.

I'm unsure how to proceed, which is why I'm posing this question.

I'm sharing my current code with you, even though it's not very extensive.

```
class InfoContainer extends StatelessWidget {
  final Color color;
  final IconData icon;
  final String text;

  const InfoContainer({
    super.key,
    required this.color,
    required this.icon,
    required this.text
  });

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return ClipRRect(
      borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(5.0),
      child: Container(
        height: 60,
        decoration: BoxDecoration(
          color: color.withOpacity(0.3),
          border: Border(
            left: BorderSide(color: color, width: 4.0),
            top: BorderSide(), // Here
            bottom: BorderSide(), // Here
          )
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: Can you share a gif, Not able to understand what you are trying to achieve

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since your usecase is outside the default behavior Flutter provides through `Border`, then it is useful to take advantage of Flutter's open source nature and inspect the underlaying classes.

By looking at `BoxDecoration`'s border property we see the parameter accepts a `BoxBorder`. This is what `Border` implements, since `Border` does not cover this use-case we can create a custom implementation of `BoxBorder`.

I have implemented a custom implementation named `InclinedBorder` that can have a pair of inclined borders eighter vertically or horizontally. Making a custom implementation of `BoxBorder` requires you to tell Flutter how to paint the border through a canvas in the `paint` method which requires some math.

#### End result

[image: Inclined borders showing vertical and horizonal configuration]

#### `InclinedBorder` implementation:

```dart
class InclinedBorder extends BoxBorder {
  final Axis inclineAxis;
  final double inclinedBorderStartWidth;
  final double inclinedBorderEndWidth;
  final double startBorderConstantWidth;
  final double endBorderConstantWidth;

  // The paint implementation have a minor gap between the border-sides this
  // corrects it.
  final double gapCorrection = 0.5;

  const InclinedBorder({
    required this.inclineAxis,
    required this.inclinedBorderStartWidth,
    required this.inclinedBorderEndWidth,
    required this.startBorderConstantWidth,
    required this.endBorderConstantWidth,
  });

  @override
  void paint(
    Canvas canvas,
    Rect rect, {
    TextDirection? textDirection,
    BoxShape shape = BoxShape.rectangle,
    BorderRadius? borderRadius,
  }) {
    final paint = Paint();

    switch (inclineAxis) {
      case Axis.horizontal:
        paint.strokeWidth = startBorderConstantWidth;
        canvas.drawLine(
            rect.topLeft - Offset(startBorderConstantWidth / 2, gapCorrection),
            rect.bottomLeft -
                Offset(startBorderConstantWidth / 2, -gapCorrection),
            paint);
        paint.strokeWidth = endBorderConstantWidth;
        canvas.drawLine(
            rect.topRight +
                Offset(endBorderConstantWidth / 2, -gapCorrection),
            rect.bottomRight +
                Offset(endBorderConstantWidth / 2, gapCorrection),
            paint);

        paint.style = PaintingStyle.fill;

        Path path = Path();
        path.moveTo(
            rect.topLeft.dx - startBorderConstantWidth, rect.topLeft.dy);
        path.lineTo(rect.topLeft.dx - startBorderConstantWidth,
            rect.topLeft.dy - inclinedBorderStartWidth);
        path.lineTo(rect.topRight.dx + endBorderConstantWidth,
            rect.topRight.dy - inclinedBorderEndWidth);
        path.lineTo(
            rect.topRight.dx + endBorderConstantWidth, rect.topRight.dy);

        path.moveTo(
            rect.bottomLeft.dx - startBorderConstantWidth, rect.bottomLeft.dy);
        path.lineTo(rect.bottomLeft.dx - startBorderConstantWidth,
            rect.bottomLeft.dy + inclinedBorderStartWidth);
        path.lineTo(rect.bottomRight.dx + endBorderConstantWidth,
            rect.bottomRight.dy + inclinedBorderEndWidth);
        path.lineTo(
            rect.bottomRight.dx + endBorderConstantWidth, rect.bottomRight.dy);

        canvas.drawPath(path, paint);
        break;

      case Axis.vertical:
        paint.strokeWidth = startBorderConstantWidth;

        canvas.drawLine(
            rect.topLeft - Offset(gapCorrection, startBorderConstantWidth / 2),
            rect.topRight -
                Offset(-gapCorrection, startBorderConstantWidth / 2),
            paint);
        paint.strokeWidth = endBorderConstantWidth;
        canvas.drawLine(
            rect.bottomLeft +
                Offset(-gapCorrection, endBorderConstantWidth / 2),
            rect.bottomRight +
                Offset(gapCorrection, endBorderConstantWidth / 2),
            paint);

        paint.style = PaintingStyle.fill;
        paint.strokeWidth = 1;

        Path path = Path();
        path.moveTo(
            rect.topLeft.dx, rect.topLeft.dy - startBorderConstantWidth);
        path.lineTo(rect.topLeft.dx - inclinedBorderStartWidth,
            rect.topLeft.dy - startBorderConstantWidth);
        path.lineTo(rect.bottomLeft.dx - inclinedBorderEndWidth,
            rect.bottomLeft.dy + endBorderConstantWidth);
        path.lineTo(
            rect.bottomLeft.dx, rect.bottomLeft.dy + endBorderConstantWidth);

        path.moveTo(
            rect.topRight.dx, rect.topRight.dy - startBorderConstantWidth);
        path.lineTo(rect.topRight.dx + inclinedBorderStartWidth,
            rect.topRight.dy - startBorderConstantWidth);
        path.lineTo(rect.bottomRight.dx + inclinedBorderEndWidth,
            rect.bottomRight.dy + endBorderConstantWidth);
        path.lineTo(
            rect.bottomRight.dx, rect.bottomRight.dy + endBorderConstantWidth);

        canvas.drawPath(path, paint);
        break;
    }
  }

  @override
  BorderSide get top => BorderSide(
        width: inclineAxis == Axis.horizontal
            ? max(inclinedBorderStartWidth, inclinedBorderEndWidth)
            : startBorderConstantWidth,
      );

  @override
  BorderSide get bottom => BorderSide(
        width: inclineAxis == Axis.horizontal
            ? max(inclinedBorderStartWidth, inclinedBorderEndWidth)
            : endBorderConstantWidth,
      );

  @override
  EdgeInsetsGeometry get dimensions {
    switch (inclineAxis) {
      case Axis.horizontal:
        return EdgeInsets.fromLTRB(
          startBorderConstantWidth,
          max(inclinedBorderStartWidth, inclinedBorderEndWidth),
          endBorderConstantWidth,
          max(inclinedBorderStartWidth, inclinedBorderEndWidth),
        );
      case Axis.vertical:
        return EdgeInsets.fromLTRB(
          max(inclinedBorderStartWidth, inclinedBorderEndWidth),
          startBorderConstantWidth,
          max(inclinedBorderStartWidth, inclinedBorderEndWidth),
          endBorderConstantWidth,
        );
    }
  }

  @override
  bool get isUniform => false;

  // TODO: This has not been implemented.
  @override
  ShapeBorder scale(double t) => throw UnimplementedError();
}
```

#### Example usage / Code behind image

Pay attention to the `Container`'s margin and the usage of the `InclinedBorder`/`BoxBorder`'s dimension property to set the margin correctly.

```dart
import 'dart:math';

import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

main() => runApp(const MaterialApp(home: BorderTestScreen()));

class BorderTestScreen extends StatelessWidget {
  const BorderTestScreen({super.key});

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    InclinedBorder border1 = const InclinedBorder(
      inclineAxis: Axis.horizontal,
      inclinedBorderStartWidth: 20,
      inclinedBorderEndWidth: 10,
      startBorderConstantWidth: 20,
      endBorderConstantWidth: 20,
    );

    InclinedBorder border2 = const InclinedBorder(
      inclineAxis: Axis.vertical,
      inclinedBorderStartWidth: 20,
      inclinedBorderEndWidth: 10,
      startBorderConstantWidth: 20,
      endBorderConstantWidth: 20,
    );

    return Scaffold(
      body: Center(
        child: Column(
            mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
            crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.center,
            children: [
              Container(
                margin: border1.dimensions,
                decoration: BoxDecoration(
                  color: Colors.green,
                  border: border1,
                ),
                child: const SizedBox(
                  width: 300,
                  height: 100,
                ),
              ),
              const SizedBox(
                height: 8,
              ),
              Container(
                margin: border2.dimensions,
                decoration: BoxDecoration(
                  color: Colors.green,
                  border: border2,
                ),
                child: const SizedBox(
                  width: 300,
                  height: 100,
                ),
              )
            ]),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Note: if you are going to use this, consider creating a widget that abstracts away the dimension logic.

Hope this helps!

Comment: Corrected a math error for smaller values, the image will look slightly different.